# Is there any way to wrap a token in quotes with a #define?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

With a C++ preprocessor directive I would need to achieve something like this:

```
std :: cout << wrapinquotes(hithere) << std :: endl;
```

and get `hithere` printed out. I tried naively doing something like

```
#define wrapinquotes(x) "x"
```

but as you can easily imagine, I got an `x` printed out. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yup, and the accepted answer (two macros) is the solution.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Thanks!